# Percent point function (PPF) in scala for a normal distribution

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I was wondering what is the equivalent Scala function to compute the Percent point function of a normal distribution as in python one can use the Scipy function `scipy.stats.norm.ppf(x)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `inverseCdf` function in [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze).
Example with the normal distribution:

```scala
import breeze.stats.distributions._
val med = Gaussian(0, 1).inverseCdf(0.5) // 0.0
```